# I tried to reinstall MySQL on centos and now it doesn't start

Tags: mysql

I tried to reinstall MySQL and now it doesn't even start, and if I go to "messages" it says this

```
Jul 23 11:04:27 systemd: Starting MySQL Server...
Jul 23 11:04:29 systemd: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 23 11:04:29 systemd: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jul 23 11:04:29 systemd: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jul 23 11:04:29 systemd: mysqld.service failed.
```

Comment: Is it hanging there or is it bouncing you back to the desktop? In the first case, it could be enough to do `CTRL + ALT + DELETE` to SIGTERM the service.

Comment: It's on centos server

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, this is a pure admin issue, therefore it is off-topic here on SO. You can get more help at the DBA sister site of SO. When you post your question there, pls make sure that you include the relevant entries from the MySQL log because nobody can tell based on the data you provided what went wrong.